# How can i solve 500 Internal Server Error during only product export

Tags: magento-1.9, error, export

I try to export my whole products, i get  **500 Internal Server Error during only  product export.**

Export :

[image]

Export Error :

[image]

**Note :**  When i try to export minimum of products like 100's of products, my export working and **bulk export only not working**.

Comment: I suggest you to do cleanup for once in your server
 https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php

Comment: may i know purpose of this script.

Comment: it will clean the cache and set proper permission to all directory

Comment: so this one can fixed my bulk product export  error,  right ??

Comment: @BhupendraJadeja : Not solve the problem, same error

Comment: Please update this question with all information from your other questions + comments on the same topic. It is not fair to open many questions on the same issue at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Since Magento is not able to catch and handle this error, it means the error is from server issue.

You need to check server error logs to know more:

- If your website is hosted in Ubuntu and you are running apache
  server, you need to check `/var/log/apache2/error_log`.
- If your website is hosted in Ubuntu and you are running nginx server,
  you need to check `/var/log/nginx/error_log`.
- For any other environment, you need to check appropriate
  documentation.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Am hosting my site in Linux Hosting

Comment: there is no error location like this

Comment: If your website is hosted in Ubuntu and you are running apache server, you need to check /var/log/apache2/error_log.

If your website is hosted in Ubuntu and you are running nginx server, you need to check /var/log/nginx/error_log.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6K3t9lB.png

Comment: Apart from magento's /var/log folder, you need to check server's error logs also.
Please contact your server administrator to get error logs of server.

Comment: where is that file can be stored

Comment: @ chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42424/what-is-the-suggested-value-of-max-execution-time-and-memory-limit-for-20-000-pro

Comment: okay, i am go to ask my host providers regard this error

Answer (score 1):

A 500 error output isn't really enough information to help you diagnose a problem like this. You need to check your server logs to get a more accurate account of what is actually going wrong.

That said, given that the export is working in small volumes but not larger ones its likely that your reaching a resource limit. At a guess I would say  phps memory limit. Again you would need to check your logs to confirm this.